# The || function isnt working when checking for user id

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!')) 
{ 
if(message.author.id !== ('490510038469705747')  || message.author.id !==('752606131569950800)') || message.author.id !==('422003274045063179') || message.author.id !==('395291950690861057')) 
    return message.channel.send('!You aint my master! ._.');
}
```

this code doesnt work, and it always just says You aint my master to anyone thats running the command
please help

i am using discord.js with visual studio code

Comment: Small tip for the future: `||` isn't a function, it's a _logical operator_.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `&&` instead of `||`. When you're using `||`, the `if` statement will pass even if only one of the parameters resolves to `true`. If you use `&&`, the `if` statement will only pass if ALL of the parameters resolve to true.

Additionally it seems you've got a stray parenthese in one of your strings `message.author.id !==('752606131569950800)')`.

Comment: i dont want all the parameters to reslove as true. my id cant be 4 different ids at once. i only want a true if, one of them are true, but the other 3 ids arent being checked, so if someone wiht the id tries a cmd it doesnt pass through

Comment: Yes, the point is to check that the user's id is none of them in your if statement. `message.author.id !== "whatever"` would resolve to `true` if `message.author.id` is not equal to `whatever`, therefore if the user's ID matches none of them all the statements resolve to `true`. Check out [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more about logical operators & comparisons.

Comment: i use ```||``` to check whether is doesnt equal to any of the ids

Comment: oh wait, i think i know what you mean. so i use ```&&``` and if any of the ids dont match, it will return with ````false``` and therfore wont execute the code. if i put in the rest of my code underneath the if statement? thanks for the help, i now undertsand what you mean:)